# Python Django use mysql function SHA2('pass',256)

Tags: python, django, django-models, mysql-python

I am creating application in Django and now I want create table with username and password. Right now, we generating password with mysql function SHA2('password',256) and my question... is possible use it the same in Django model? I mean everything what will be save to password row, will be saved as hash sha2 in admin app or I must create functions?

this is my models.py

```
class Users(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    status = models.IntegerField()
    valid_from = models.DateTimeField()
    valid_to  = models.DateTimeField()
    online  = models.IntegerField()
    ip = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    created  = models.DateTimeField()

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.username}'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to create `User` model. You can use this instead. `from django.contrib.auth.models import User`.

then you can add additional field into model if you want

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    valid_from = models.DateTimeField()
    valid_to  = models.DateTimeField()
    online  = models.IntegerField()
    ip = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    created  = models.DateTimeField()
```

You can read it in details in [Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/auth/) here.